# How do we get the gear icon back on modern pages?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, top-link-bar

How do we get the gear icon back on the top nav bar of modern pages? No changes have been made (design/CSS/master page). Gear icon disappeared from modern pages on April 24, 2019. The gear icon IS available on classic pages and list pages.

Comment: Do you mean the gear icon in the top-right of the suite bar? It's there on all the modern pages in the tenant I use. Could you post a screen capture?

Comment: Yes, that's the one - the gear icon in the top-right of the suite bar. It was on all modern pages in our tenant until yesterday. How can I get it back?

Comment: Have you checked to see if there have been any permission changes? That's the only reason I can think of that would hide it.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior whether I'm logged in as SP Admin, regular user (E5) with SCA permissions, or E1 user with view only rights. I've also tried both IE and Chrome. The gear is visible and works as expected from classic pages and list pages, but is missing from modern pages.

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to open a support ticket with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

You have a customization that is interfering with an update made by Microsoft on your tenant. Most likely you've created a global object that's now colliding with platform code.

You'll need to update your customizations to back this out.

The reason I now this is, it happened to me as well.